# Memory usage in C++ program

Tags: c++, memory, vector, boost-unordered

I wrote a program that needs to handle a very large data with the following libraries:

- vector
- boost::unordered_map
- boost::unordered_multimap

So, I'm having memory problems (The program uses a LOT) and I was thinking maybe I can replace this libraries (with something that already exists or my own implementations):

So, three questions:

- How much memory I'd save if I replace vector with a C array? Is it worth it?
- Can someone explain how is the memory used in boost::unordered_map and boost::unordered_multimap in the current implementation? Like what's stored in order to achieve their performance.
- Can you recommend me some libraries that outperform boost::unordered_map and boost::unordered_multimap in memory usage (But not something too slow) ?

Comment: The first point isn't worth it unless you allocate stuff on the stack (and that might be risky, depends on your application).

Comment: Which compiler? Which C++ standard library? Try a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. `g++-4.9 -std=c++11 -Wall -O -g`) and use C++11 STL i.e. `std::unordered_map`

Comment: Approximately how many elements do you have in your array? Of what size?

Comment: I would be surprised if any of these types stored much more than the elements you put in them and a few extra internal objects. If you're going to be storing that many elements in them anyway, well then that's how big they're going to be, regardless of who implements it.

Comment: Replacing `std::vector` with an array may save you about 20 bytes. `std::vector` is re-sizable, an array is not, that should be the decision base. Maps can be replaced by a sorted `std::vector`, so memory overhead is zero and searching is probably faster, but insertion and deletion is slow. If you rarely do that it works well.

Comment: std::vector allocates contiguous memory, try using std::deque. Usually this translates to: pretty much same memory used, but a lot less std::bad_alloc exceptions

Comment: What are the types stored in your map?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm using g++-4.7 with all the flags you specified. Why use std::unordered_map instead of boost::unordered_map?

Comment: @Ben In the vectors the biggest object I have is a vector<vector<unsinged long int> (Yes is a vector of vector of vectors), each vector of unsigned long is of size 8 and I can have at most 1500 vectors. So, 12k unsigned long ints, 8 bytes each, 96K for each element I think (correct me if I'm wrong please). Now, the number of objects I'm handling is about 700k.

Comment: @NeilKirk I'm storing unsigned long integers

Comment: Lots of stuff you are asking... you are better off breaking down your question into much simpler and specific parts (you are more likely to receive useful help).

Comment: @Jcao02: GCC 4.9 improved a lot since 4.7, and is C++11 compatible with an improved C++ library. So consider upgrading your GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by changing `boost::unordered_multimap` for `std::unordered_map` of `vector`.

`boost::unordered_multimap` consumes more than two times the memory consumed by   `std::unordered_map` of `vector` due the extra pointers it keeps (at least one extra pointer per element) and the fact that it stores the key and the value of each element, while `unordered_map` of `vector` only stores the key once for a vector that contains all the colliding elements.

In my particular case, I was trying to store about 4k million integers, consuming about 15 GB of memory in the ideal case. Using the multimap I get to consume more than 40 GB while using the map I use about 15 GB (a little bit more due the pointers and other structures but their size if despicable).

Answer (score 5):

`std::vector` is memory efficient. I don't know about the boost maps, but the Boost people usually know what they're doing, I doubt you'll save a lot of memory by creating your own variants.

You can do a few other things to help with memory issues:

1. Compile in 64 bit. Running out of memory in a 64 bit process is *very* hard.
2. You won't run out of memory, but memory might get swapped out. You should instead see if you need to load everything into memory at once, perhaps you can work on chunks of the data at a time.
3. As a side benefit, working on a chunk of the data at a time allows you to run your code in parallel.

With memory being so cheap nowadays, so that allocating 10GB of RAM is very simple, I guess your bottlenecks will be in the processing you do of the data, not of allocating the data.

Comment: Well, actually the program runs in a server of 128 GB of RAM, and I'm consuming 90 GB. I'm using only pointers to the structures I mentioned, so they are allocated in the heap, and I'm using primitive types and objects of C++ std libraries (unsigned long, vectors, etc)

Comment: Do you need all 90GB of information in memory at once? Just reading 90GB of data into memory and placing it in a map should take a while. Won't you benefit from keeping the data in a database?

Comment: Yes it does take like 4 hours. The thing is the search in the maps has to be fast and I think reading the data from the disk can be slow. But I'll test that, thanks

Comment: If you're searching for basic data in the maps (that is, numbers, strings, not picture or videos or such), definitely use a database. Load the data once and then perform queries on it. It will be *a lot* faster.

Answer (score 1):

These two articles explain the data structures underyling some common implementations of unordered associative containers:

- [Implementation of C++ unordered associative containers](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2013/10/implementation-of-c-unordered.html)
- [Implementation of C++ unordered associative containers with duplicate elements](http://bannalia.blogspot.com/2013/10/implementation-of-c-unordered_25.html)

Even though there are some differences between implementations, they are modest --one word per element at most. If you go with minimum-overhead solutions such as sorted vectors, this would gain you 2-3 words per element, not even a 2x improvement if your objects are large. So, you'd probably be better off resorting to an environment with more memory or radically changing your approach by using a database or something.

Answer (score 0):

std::vector is basically a contiguous array, plus a few bytes of overhead. About the only way you'll improve with vector is by using a smaller element type. Can you store a short int instead of a regular int? If so, you can cut the vector memory down by half.

Are you perhaps using these containers to hold pointers to many objects on the heap? If so, you may have a lot of wasted space in the heap that could be saved by writing custom allocators, or by doing away with a pointer to a heap element altogether, and by storing a value type within the container.

Look within your class types. Consider all pointer types, and whether they need to be dynamic storage or not. The typical class often has pointer members hanging off a base object, which means a single object is a graph of memory chunks in itself. The more you can inline your class members, the more efficient your use of the heap will be.

RAM is cheap in 2014. Easy enough to build x86-64 Intel boxes with 64-256GB of RAM and Solid State Disk as fast swap if your current box isn't cutting it for the project. Hopefully this isn't a commercial desktop app we are discussing. :)

Comment: Nope, is a part of my final project for my degree. I'm using only pointers to the structures, but the structures themselves store the objects and not pointers... I think I'm doing right since the size of the containers are potentially huge and the stack couldn't handle that (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: With regards to `std::vector`, it depends.  If he's not pre-allocating it to correct size, but just building it up using `push_back`, it can use a lot more memory than necessary.

Comment: @JamesKanze Could you please be more specific about that?. Because I'm actually using push_back a lot.

Comment: @Jcao02 If `push_back` requires an increase in the capacity, the implementation will multiply the current capacity by a constant factor (usually either 1.5 or 2), and allocate additional memory for that many elements.  It will free the old memory.  This means that at times, your vector may use almost twice the size it actually needs, and of course, this allocating and freeing leads to fragmentation; very often the freed blocks can never be used in the vector later (but they may be usable by the various map types you're using).

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one set of data and multiple ways of accessing it you can try to use `boost::multi_index` here is the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html).